# Make a hfer tag using display-tag library

Tags: java, displaytag

I have the following code which generates a table according to the data in the list "dataList" using displaytag library. This works fine.

```
<display:table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" partialList="true" size="totalSearchResults" id="product-table" name="dataList" pagesize="6" export="false" requestURI="/edit">

<display:column  property="firstname" title="First Name"  sortable="true"/>
<display:column property="lastname" title="Last Name" sortable="true"/>

<display:column class="options-width">
    <a href="delete?emp="${empno}>Delete</a>
</display:column>
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
</display:table>
```

I need to create the href by appending the employee number as a query string as shown. But after executing the code the url displays as ....delete?emp= without appending the employee number in to it. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`<a href="delete?emp="${empno}>Delete</a>`
to
`<a href="delete?emp=${empno}">Delete</a>`